# O que é um AppDomain?

Tags: c#, .net

[Fui ler sobre isso no site da Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bh4z9hs(v=vs.110).aspx). Seria interessante ter uma resposta sucinta aqui em português com um resumo do que é?

Tem alguma coisa importante que não consta na documentação?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O AppDomain, ou domínio de aplicação, é mais ou menos como se fosse um processo dentro de outro processo. Ele tem um certo isolamento dos outros AppDomains. Ele não é muito usado, mas é útil especialmente se tem algum sistema de *plugin* na aplicação. Como você pode executar um código que não tem controle de forma relativamente segura? A resposta é o AppDomain. Se o código de um AppDomain quebrar ele não quebra todo o processo.

Os níveis de segurança de cada um podem ser definidos independentemente, então algum AppDomain pode ser proibido de fazer certas operações criando um *sandbox*.

Outra vantagem dele é que pode ser carregado ou descarregado sob demanda não ocupando memória sem necessidade ou pode ser só pausado. Pode carregar *assemblies* de versões diferentes como já foi falando na minha resposta anterior.

A comunicação é feita de forma serializada, então há pouca ou nenhuma vantagem em relação a ter outro processo nesse ponto. Não há compartilhamento de memória, assim como no processo. *Threads* são compartilhadas entre eles, e isto é uma enorme diferença para o processo. Ele é um pouco mais barato que um processo completo, funciona quase como uma *thread* sem compartilhar a memória de forma direta.

Ele é complexo, a não ser que tenha um caso muito importante para uso, fique longe dele. Se for criar é com a classe [`AppDomain`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0).

O .NET Core não tem esse mecanismo, e como [ele é o único futuro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101) não deve ser usado.