# Qual o tamanho mínimo de um objeto na memória?

Tags: c#, .net, memória, objetos

Recebi [uma resposta em pergunta minha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/200715/101) que fala sobre um *overhead* que o objeto tem. Todo objeto tem esse *overhead*?

Um objeto sem dados também tem esse *overhead*?

Existe objeto de tamanho 0?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

O [*overhead*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/198252/101) só ocorre em [tipos por referência. Em tipos por valor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101) ele não ocorre nunca, é só o custo do objeto mesmo. Pelo menos não o *overhead* do cabeçalho.

Todo objeto está sujeito ao alinhamento ([organização de classes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/161846/101)). Então cada alocação precisa ser múltiplo de uma [palavra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/185523/101). Em 64 bits deve ser sempre a cada 16 bytes. Então se o objeto tiver 25 bytes, na verdade ele terá 32 bytes.

Se for um tipo por referência sempre terá um cabeçalho com duas palavras.

Uma é o indicador de tipo do objeto. Ele é importante para o coletor de lixo, para saber sobre o polimorfismo, *cast*, reflexão, etc.

A outra palavra é chamada de *syncblock* que costuma ser usado para indicar onde está um objeto de monitoramento em objetos compartilhados entre *threads*.

Como na verdade não é tão comum o seu uso assim, ele pode ser usado para outras coisas. Uma dessas coisas é fazer cache do [*hash code* do objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191257/101).

É usada também pelo GC para fazer seu controle durante a fase de *mark* do que ainda está vivo ou não.

[Objetos COM](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/198929/101) precisam de uma referência para externa e este espaço é usado para isto.

Ainda pode conter o ID do [`AppDomain`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191768/101) em alguns casos.

Mas tem uma pegadinha. Nenhum objeto tem menos que 12 bytes em 32 bits, ou 24 bytes em 64 bits. O objeto deve ter pelo menos uma palavra de "estado do objeto", mesmo que ele seja vazio. Mas se você tiver um objeto com uma palavra, esse custo não é adicionado, ele continua com 12 ou 24 bytes de tamanho.

Então não só um objeto por referência tem esse *overhead*, mas ele tem mais um *overhead* se ele for vazio ou inferior a uma palavra.

Tipos por referência não podem ter tamanho 0 de acordo com o exposto acima. Tipos por valor ocupam pelo menos 1 byte. Isso pode ser verificado com:

```
using System;

class Program {
    static void Main() {
        var memoriaAnterior = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
        Console.WriteLine(memoriaAnterior);
        var array = new None[1000000];
        var memoriaAtual = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
        Console.WriteLine(memoriaAtual);
        Console.WriteLine($"Diferença: { memoriaAtual - memoriaAnterior }");
        Console.WriteLine(array.Length);
    }
}

struct None {}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/DoLnF2). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7Onf5C). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Memory/ZeroObejectAllocation.cs).

Para entender um pouco mais: [Como o "free()" sabe quanto de memória tem que liberar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178174/101)

Note que tudo isto depende de implementação. Existem várias implementações do CLR. [Podemos ver uma forma diferente](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/managed-object-internals-part-1-layout/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Comment: Cada vez que leio um poste seu, me animo a estudar mais, vejo que tem domínio sobre todos assuntos abordados.

Comment: @DiegoFarias obrigado, mas me falta muita coisa ainda. Eu acabei de aprender uma coisa que eu não sabia criando essa resposta.

Comment: Nossa que bacana, estou tentando acompanhar os conteúdos ao máximo que posso, e mesmo lendo as respostas do fórum, já aprendi bastante coisa, estamos aprendendo o tempo todo.