# O que é o syncblock?

Tags: c#, .net, memória, objetos, concorrência

[Recebi uma resposta que falava sobre um *syncblock*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/200965/522). Por que ele é necessário?

Pelo que entendi no que pesquisei é sobre controle de concorrência. Mas por que todo objeto precisa dele se nem todos terão concorrência?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De fato a função principal dele é o controle de concorrência, mas não é a única, de alguma forma teria que existir esse "bloco" no cabeçalho do objeto.

Ele tem o endereço de um objeto de sincronização que garantirá o controle sobre o acesso ao objeto. O objeto de sincronização é mais complexo, não poderia estar em cada objeto, então é colocado só uma referência para esse objeto.

Algumas pessoas acham que não deveria ter por padrão e só os objetos que realmente podem ser sincronizados é que deveria ter esse *overhead*. Mas na prática quase todo objeto pode ser sincronizado, ainda que em geral não sejam. É uma complicação ter que ficar escolhendo isso se quase todos terão esse custo.

Sem ele a sincronização teria que ser feita pelo sistema operacional o que implica em troca de contexto de execução que é algo bem caro em processamento. Então optou-se por gastar um pouco de memória para ter um mecanismo próprio de sincronização que é bem mais rápido.

Poderiam ter optado por alguma outra forma. Poderia ter uma tabela global de controle. Haveria um custo de processamento extra para achar o objeto na tabela, mas economizaria espaço. Mas ou acharam essa solução melhor ou não pensaram nisso antes.

[image: Syncblock]

Answer (score 3):

## Garantia de sincronização

Uma função do *syncblock* é fazer esse controle de concorrência em um sistema multitarefa. Não sei se é nesse sentido que você tem dúvida, mas vou colocar um exemplo.

Suponha que em seu sistema você tenha uma classe que implementa um `Singleton`. Nesse cenário existe então uma instância de uma classe rodando no sistema e essa instância é única para qualquer chamada que for feita aos métodos. 
Se você tiver dois `thread` rodando no sistema e isso significa que os dois podem chamar o mesmo método do `Singleton` ao mesmo tempo. Se você não fizer nenhum controle, dependendo do código que é executado no método, o seu programa pode funcionar de forma incorreta.

Uma das formas de garantir que essas duas chamadas não terão problemas de execução, é preciso sincronizar a execução delas, ou seja, você precisa garantir que se os dois `thread` chamarem o método ao mesmo tempo, um vai executar antes do outro e assim não haverá interferência. Para isso, usamos aquele bloco de comando `lock` do .NET.

Por exemplo, vou apresentar um código para implementa um  `Singleton` de forma segura e sincronizada para um sistema multitarefa:

```
public sealed class Session
{

    private static volatile Session instance;
    private static object sync = new Object();

    private Session() { }

    public static Session Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                lock (sync)
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                    {
                        instance = new Session();
                    }
                }
            }
            return instance;
        }

    }

}
```

O bloco do `lock` ativa esse controle na variável `sync` alocando a posse do controle de execução para aquele `thread` que chamou o método `Instance`. Dessa forma, quando o segundo `thread` chamar o mesmo método `Instance`, o sistema vai tentar chamar o `lock` para o `sync` e o resultado vai ser um bloqueio temporário na execução daquele segundo `thread`. Quando o primeiro `thread` sair do bloco `lock`, ele vai liberar o controle na variável `sync` permitindo assim o desbloqueio do segundo `thread` e a continuação da execução dele.

A forma como o código de exemplo foi implementado vai garantir que apenas uma instância da classe `Session` seja criada. O segundo `thread` que rodar, quando passar pelo `lock` vai identificar que a instância já foi criada e vai receber ela. Se não houvesse esse controle, existiria uma chance de cada um dos `thread` receber uma instância nova da classe `Session` e então não teríamos mais um `Singleton`.

O que o seu programa fez foi criar uma espécie de sincronização forçada naquela parte do código para que não seja executada por dois threads ao mesmo tempo. O `syncblock` então é uma área reservada na memória para aquele objeto para que ele permita usar essa função de sincronização em certos pontos críticos do código.

Comment: Muito boa explicação.