# Pode armazenar hash code em um banco de dados?

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, .net, string

Estava lendo algumas perguntas aqui e [surgiu uma dúvida em uma dessas perguntas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/191260/101).

Se eu tiver uma aplicação que eu preciso armazenar strings em um banco de dados para comparar depois com alguma coisa, mas eu não preciso dos textos, só precisa saber se são iguais, não seria melhor eu armazenar o *hash code* que é curto no lugar do texto? Pelo que li, me corrija se estiver errado, que o `switch` usa o *hash code* para selecionar strings então eu queria fazer a mesma coisa.

Comment: acredito que sim, porém, há a possibilidade de conflitos que deve ser levado em conta, não tenho maiores informações para formular uma resposta, apenas minha opinião =]

Comment: A resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não pode. O *hash code* não é estável, ele pode usar fórmulas diferentes dependendo da versão usada. Mais ainda, até mesmo dentro da mesma execução da aplicação pode haver um algoritmo diferente se tiver mais de um [`AppDomain`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191768/101) já que cada um pode rodar uma versão diferente do CLR ou até mesmo do código da sua aplicação. Mesmo que não use `AppDomain`, ainda tem problema (isso não existe mais no .NET Core).

Ainda é possível ter duas *strings* diferentes com o mesmo *hash code*, então não pode confiar nisso. O `switch` usa o mecanismo do *hash code* apenas para melhorar a performance de seleção, mas depois ele confirma se é aquilo mesmo com a própria *string*, o que já é bem melhor de comprar todas *strings*. Para fazer o mesmo com o banco de dados teria que armazenar a *string* de qualquer jeito. Como é um banco de dados o ganho de performance será irrisório, não vale o esforço.

Se quer arriscar ter colisões, ou seja, se o seu caso elas não importam, o ideal seria criar um sistema de *hash code* próprio para não depender da implementação do .NET ou outra implementação do [CLR](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101) que pode usar um algoritmo bem diferente de qualquer outra versão do .NET já que não há especificação do algoritmo exato. Pelo menos desta forma poderia garantir a estabilidade do algoritmo.

Poderia armazenar os primeiros caracteres da *string* junto do *hash code*, assim é muito improvável, mas não garantido, que tenha uma colisão de código com o início igual. Ainda há risco, mas ele é bem baixo, "quase" o mesmo que usar um [GUID](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40525/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).