# Como armazenar hash em um banco de dados?

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, .net, hash, persistência

Eu vi em [Pode armazenar hash code em um banco de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227349/101) que não pode armazenar o código hash de um objeto, mas se eu tiver *strings* que eu preciso armazenar o *hash* no banco de dados, não tem o que fazer? Ou existe solução para isto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É possível armazenar sim um *hash* em um banco de dados, mas precisa saber o que está fazendo.

Não pode armazenar o *hash* padrão do C# indiscriminadamente. Pode até armazenar o que a linguagem cria de forma padrão, mas tem que estar preparado e não causar problema se mudar a implementação, e precisa ter uma estratégia de correção se mudar. Então só pode usar assim em alguns casos e dá trabalho, em geral não compensa.

Só lembrando que a mudança é bem rara, então pode ser que nunca dê problema.

Fora isso pode criar um *hash* que tenha implementação estável e seja garantido que nunca mudará, por exemplo o MD5, SHA-1, ou vários outros que são usados para criptografia ou para *hashes* mais simples que esteja especificado que a implementação não pode mudar.

O mais adequado provavelmente é você fazer uma implementação muito simples e eficiente, muito mais que essas de criptografia, e que você tem controle.

Se não quiser fazer uma, como ideia, poderia pegar o código fonte, por exemplo, da *string*, que está na pergunta, e usar o gerador de *hash* que o C# usa. É copiar mesmo. A segurança que você vai ter em copiar isso é que passa ter controle, se mudar no C# a sua não muda, então pode usar de forma tranquila. [Dá uma olhada](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Marvin.cs,797a1d788badc2e7). Acho um pouco complexo, mas é bem pensado.

Provavelmente pode fazer algo bem mais simples:

```
public int StableHash(string text) {
    int hash = 23;
    foreach (char c in text) hash *= 31 + c;
    return hash;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/HashString.cs).

Não é ótima para evitar colisões, mas para armazenar pode ser suficiente para o objetivo específico. Se não for, procure outras formas melhores.

Comment: Armazenar em base64, em `blob` ou até mesmo em um bitmap dá certo kkk

Comment: è que aí não é um hash.